# Swift NSTimer Wait Time Error

Tags: xcode, swift, nstimer

I'm using this statement:

```
 timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Double((0.01*i+0.01)), target: self, selector: Selector("Move_Loading"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

It displays an error for the Double *Could not find an overflow for '+' that accepts the supplied arguments*. What does that error mean?
(I use Double(i+1) and it works perfectly fine.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to put whitespace around binary operators like "+", "-", "/" and "*" in Swift. Swift is pickier about whitespace than C family languages.

As shown in Leo's answer (voted), the expression should be

```
0.01 * Double(i) + 0.01
```

Comment: It's not the whitespace that matters here, but the casting.

Comment: Actually it's both. Try it without the white space. It doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me. Swift lets you do `a+b` or `a + b`, just not `a+ b` or `a +b`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01 * Double(i) + 0.01, target: self, selector: "Move_Loading", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```